# Component data updated but not able to be used

Tags: vue.js, axios, vuex

I'm building a deck building app. When a user wants to add a card to their deck, they go to the AddDeck view/component. They then search for cards and when they find one the like, they add it to the deck they're building. The user clicks an "Add Card" button and that card's information gets put into an array stored as a data member of the component: [image: Data members of AddDeck component].

Another data member of this component is the deck's title. When the user is done, they click the save button and an axios request is sent to the backend (the deck name as a URL parameter and the deckCards array in the request body). Additionally, that deck is added to the Vuex store. Here is the code:

```
saveDeck: function () {
  axios
    .post(`http://localhost:3000/api/pages/decks/add/${this.deckName}`, {
      cards: this.deckCards
    })
    .then(() => {
      this.$store.commit('addDeck', { name: this.deckName, cards: this.deckCards })
      this.$router.push({ path: '../dash' })
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      throw err
    })
}
```

This is what has me stumped: the deck name is passed fine to the backend and to the store, but the deck cards are passed to neither the store nor backend, even though the Vue DevTools show it as in the component's data. The only thing I could think of it being is the fact that `deckCards` is an array of objects while `deckTitle` is just a string. Is there something special I have to do to update the array data in the component or send/parse the array data so that it can be used?

Comment: I had them in there for troubleshooting to make sure that wasn’t the problem. I have removed them.

Comment: Check your browser's _Network_ console to confirm what is sent in the request body. How is `deckCards` initialised in your component `data`? How do you add to it?